# Problem with non-nullable columns with default values in EF data model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a DB table with two int columns that are not nullable, but are defined with default values of zero.  Both columns are not used in the model I am busy with, so I am trying to keep then out of the conceptual model.  If I delete them there, I get uphill because the store model columns are not mapped.  If I delete them from the store model, or add defaults in the store model, my changes get undone whenever I update the model.  It seems a pretty poor showing to me that the designer doesn't honour SQL server default values for the columns, and neither am I really allowed to intervene and do this job for it.  How can I ignore these columns without changing my db schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the designer is somethimes very annoying, when you have to modify the xml file directly for (sometimes not very) advanced scenarios.

A possible workaround for your problem might be to use a view instead of the table. just create a view without the two columns and EF won't see the columns anymore.

Comment: I think an easier workaround is to just keep the two damned fields and ignore them :-/  Using a view also introduces work when I want to do inserts and updates.

Comment: Yes i know, so you can choose beween: have some work with creating a view or have some work to manual update your xml after updating your model. For myself i just dont update the model anymore after manual editing the xml. I can continue to work with the designer if i just dont ever click on "Update Model" - i know, thats not really a kind of workaround...